# Automating the task of figuring out if a task is classification or regression

Tags: classification, regression, supervised-learning

When manually identifying if a given dataset and dependent variable are suitable for classification or regression I look at the type of variable (continuous or discrete) in which the name and values of the variable play a big role:

name=height, values=["short", "tall"] --> classification

name=height, values=[range between 160 and 180cm] --> regression

name=height, values=[exactly 2 values: 10.5cm and 15.5cm] --> could be either but likely classification

How can I get a function to automatically detect, with high certainty, if a given (dataset, label column) pair is ideal for classification or regression? Are there known techniques that do this well?